# Twig Error after updating by using composer

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to learn how to use symfony, but I got this error after updating via composer and I don't understand how to solve it.

```
Twig_Error_Syntax in classes.php line 5280:
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in C:\wamp64\www\symfony\var\cache\dev\classes.php on line 5573 and defined") in "@Twig/Exception/exception_full.html.twig".
```

PHP -v :

```
PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 09:48:53) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

If someone can tell me what to do, I would appreciate \o/

Thanks !

I used this cmd to update :

```
C:\wamp64\www\symfony>php ../composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 10 updates, 0 removals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some strange problem with new twig version and some (wamp/xamp) servers .

You need to change twig version in composer.json to

```
"twig/twig": "~1.28"
```

and reinstall vendors ( remove composer.lock, remove vendor dir  and composer install )

Answer (score 0):

Follow the proper install instruction for windows:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Then make sure you can run the command `composer` directly from the command line (anywhere), not composer.phar.

In your command `php ..composer.phar update`, you are going up one level. But instead if "C:\wamp64\www\symfony" is your Symfony project location, you should be entering:

```
C:\wamp64\www\symfony>composer update
```

Let us know once you've done that to see if that resolves the issue.